# frida:no response after hook

Tags: java, android, frida

I hook a function with no error, but it has no output, I can be sure that the app runs this function

```
import frida
import sys

rdev = frida.get_remote_device()

session = rdev.attach("com.che168.autotradercloud")  # "com.che168.autotradercloud" 1990

scr = """
Java.perform(function () {
    // package.class
    var SPUtils = Java.use("com.che168.autotradercloud.util.SPUtils");
    var SharedPreferencesUtil = Java.use("com.che168.atclibrary.utils.SharedPreferencesUtil");

    // This hook runs successfully

    SPUtils.saveDeviceId.implementation = function(str){
        console.log("set device_id",str);
        this.saveDeviceId(str);
    }
    
    // This hook function is in the same class as the above one, and it should have been executed, but nothing happened,no `console.log...`

    SPUtils.getDeviceId.implementation = function(){
        var res = this.getDeviceId();
        console.log("get id",res);
        return res;
    }
});
"""

script = session.create_script(scr)

def on_message(message, data):
    print(message, data)

script.on("message", on_message)

script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

The source code decompiled with jadx is as follows (in part)

```
// getSpUtil() is SharedPreferencesUtil
public static void saveDeviceId(String str) {
       getSpUtil().saveString(KEY_DEVICE_ID, str);
}

public static String getDeviceId() {
       return getSpUtil().getString(KEY_DEVICE_ID, "");
}
```

The frida-version is 16.0.1 and py version is 3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

By calling `rdev.attach("com.che168.autotradercloud")` you attach Frida to the existing instance of the app.

If you then hook functions the hook will only be executed if the app executes this function after you have attached with Frida. If the app just calls it once at app start-up then attaching to the app is too late as the call was already executed.

The only way to hook function calls that are called by the app at start-up is to spawn the app in suspended state, attach to it, load your hook script and then resume it (let it run).

```
pid = rdev.spawn("com.che168.autotradercloud")
session = rdev.attach(pid)

...
script = session.create_script(scr)
script.on("message", on_message)
script.load()

rdev.resume(pid) # make the app run
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The hook function that called `SPUtils. GetDeviceId. Implementation` is not in the app just began to perform a load, but when I click on the button in the app will perform the operation, The hook function `SPUtils. SaveDeviceId. Implementation` is app began to perform a load, the function I hook a success

Comment: @guidingg Sorry, but except from "`GetDeviceId` is called when I click a button" I don't understand what you wanted to tell me.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it very clearly. That is, `getDeviceId` executes when the button is pressed. If the hook succeeds, there will be `console.log`, but there is no `console.log`.

Comment: However, the hook of `saveDeviceId` succeeds, and `saveDeviceId` and `getDeviceId` are in the same class, so `getDeviceId` should also succeed in hook. I suspect it may be anti-debugging, if not this problem, That can only be if `getDeviceId` is not called when the button is pressed

Comment: @guidingg One thing you could try is calling ` Java.deoptimizeEverything();` at the beginning of the `Java.perform` function.

Comment: The app update today has resolved the issue with successful hooking. However, it is possible that there is a bug in the application. Nevertheless, I appreciate your assistance.